# Converting Perl script to EXE using Par Packer in Perl

Tags: perl, exe, par

I have converted an executable file using Perl Par Packer in Windows 7. But when I execute the file, it shows some error.

I think I have to add the module also, but I am not sure. I basically use `pp -o sample.exe sample.pl`

I use [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) 5.16.

[image]

It's working fine as the Perl script, but after converting into an EXE file, it terminates with the error.

Comment: Any alternative solutions to make an Perl script to exe

Comment: Does `Mojo\entries.txt` exist? Is it included in your package or relative to the file? I guess that PAR::Packer only included the necessary Perl stuff in your .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by adding the Mojo module in the same location of the standalone executing file

Comment: Are you sure all the modules needed were in your path at the time you ran 'pp'? This could be just a path issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some required modules (ByteStreams.pm, Collection.pm, DOM.pm) are missing from your perl package.

Try to download and install them using ppm (perl package manager).
1. Press start Button , type perl
2. click on ppm logo
3. search module name from search box
4. Install.

If authorization failed try to install via command prompt.

1. open cmd.
2. type: **ppm install *'module name'***
3. rebuild your exe and run.

Comment: i have installed the modules using the above method and `cpan Mojo::DOM` etc., still its not work

Answer (score 0):

I like perl , and I also like C/C++. To make the best of both,
I wrote a github project to solve this issue.

please see:
    https://github.com/tlqtangok/perlcpp

a short example is here :

```
P_eval("$a=2;$a=$a**10;"); 
Int("a") ;   // a= 1024  

P_eval("$a=qq(abc);

P_eval("@arr=(0..9);"; 
P_arr_Int_i("arr", 8 );  // => 8
```